# Validar formato cadena "Latitud, Longitud"

Tags: python, validación

tengo un control de usuario de tipo entry, y me gustaría que el usuario únicamente pueda introducir el siguiente formato:

Latitud,Longitud como por ejemplo "12.2323,-1.53452"

Es decir que solamente se pueda introducir números, puntos, 1 coma, y el signo menos. Por otra parte he leído que la latitud debe ser un número entre -90 y 90 y la longitud entre -180 y 180

Como puedo hacer esto?
Con que funciones puedo apoyarme para realizar la validación? Gracias

Comment: "control de usuario de tipo entry"... ¿Qué framework? ¿Es una gui? ¿Estás usando Tkinter, PyQt, kivy, wxPython, pygtk...? ¿Es una app web? Por favor agrega un [mcve] para que te podamos responder en base a tu caso real. Un saludo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes utilizar una expresión regular:

```
import re
patron = re.compile('^(\-?\d+(\.\d+)?),\s*(\-?\d+(\.\d+)?)$') #patrón que debe cumplir
if (not patron.match(latitud) is None) and (not patron.math(longitud) is None):
    #Código a ejecutar si son coordenadas válidas
else:
    #Código a ejecutar si las coordenadas no son válidas
```

Con `import re` importamos la librería de expresiones regulares.

`re.compile()` Compila una expresión regular.

`patron.match()` Devuelve  None si la variable no sigue la expresión regular.

**latitud** y **longitud** son las variables donde has almacenado sus respectivos valores.

---

No he añadido la comprobación de si la longitud y latitud están entre -90 y 90, es algo trivial, seguro que puedes hacerlo solo :)

Comment: Hola XBoss, gracias por la informacion, he intentado aplicarlo pero me lanza el error:
 
if (not patron.math(lat_long) is None):
AttributeError: '_sre.SRE_Pattern' object has no attribute 'math'
Traceback (most recent call last):

Comment: Creo que lo he solucionado, el error estaba en que he copiado y pegado el codigo para adaptarlo, y falta una 'c' en patron.math.

Muchas gracias, un saludo !!

Comment: De nada! que te sea útil!